# Why is my birthYear not getting the value of numYear?

Tags: javascript

Basically I want to input my date of birth at 'numYear' but it doesn't get the value.

Here's my code:

```
function myAge() {
    let myBirthYear = document.getElementById('numYear').Value;

    let result = (2020 - myBirthYear);

    //create h1 element
    let h1 = document.createElement('h1');
    let h1elem = document.createElement('class','newelem');

    let answer = document.createTextNode('You are ' + result + ' years old!');

    h1.appendChild(answer);

    document.getElementById('results').appendChild(h1);
}
```

Comment: How do you know it doesn't have the value?

Comment: `.Value` and `.value` are different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the value like this,

```
let myBirthYear = document.getElementById('numYear').value;
```

Notice the `value` instead of `Value`